# Swiftily execute arbitrary closure types with arbitrary parameters

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, closures

I want to build a manager tool that can execute a group of same-typed closures when given a tuple that matches the parameter list, but I'm having trouble coercing Swift's type system to allow it.

The general idea is that I wanted to be able to request a resource (with completion block) from any class and have the resource requested a single time and have each completion block be called when the response is gained. I've prototyped this once already and it works well, looking something like this:

```
class ResourceGetter {
    var completionQueue: [((Resource) -> Void)]?
    func getResource(withCompletion completion:((Resource) -> Void)) {
        guard completionQueue == nil else {
            completionQueue!.append(completion)
            return
        }
        ClassThatActuallyGetsIt.getResource(completion: { (res: Resource) -> Void in
            completionQueue.forEach { $0(res) }
            completionQueue = nil
        }
    }
}
```

And with that any class can call ResourceGetter.getResource and their closure will be processed when the resource is actually available.

Now I want to use this functionality in several different places around the app, but I don't want to write in a completionQueue for every resource that might be wanted, so I'm trying to figure out how to genericize (I have no idea if that's a word) this functionality.

My dream is for it to look and be used like this:

```
class CompletionHolder {
    var completionDict: [String : [((ArbitraryTuple) -> Void)]] = [:]
    func execClosures(forKey key: String, parameters: ArbitraryTuple) {
        completionDict[key].forEach { $0(parameters) }
    }
}

class ResourceGetter {
    func getResource(withCompletion completion:((Resource) -> Void)) {
        CompletionHolder.completionDict["Resource"].append(completion)
        ClassThatActuallyGetsIt.getResource(completion: { (res: Resource) -> Void in
            CompletionHolder.execClosures(forKey: "Resource", parameters: (Resource))
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: It's unclear why this wouldn't just be `struct ResourceGetter<Resource>`. I think you may be over-complicating it by trying to tie it directly into classes with inheritance. If you use composition, and let your classes *have* a `ResourceGetter`, I suspect this will be much simpler.

Comment: The desired resource may not always be a single object; if this were handling a network request, I'd want to be able to pass something like (NSError, Resource, PieceOfPertinentData).

Comment: Wrap those things into a struct or enum. Then it's one thing. (You should do that anyway for an error vs resource if exactly one must be passed.) Swift cannot have a function of unknown parameters.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't require my writing a custom struct for each class that intended to use this.